# How to ignore \n while indexing

Tags: python

I got a file with the following text:

```
with open("file1.txt", "w") as file1:
    file1.write("Thou blind fool, Love, what dost thou to mine eyes\n"
                 "That they behold, and see not what they see\n"
                 "They know what beauty is, see where it lies\n"
                 "Yet what the best is take the worst to be")
```

what I have to do is to create another file and rewrite this text but:
if a string ends with a vowel than I have to put "way" after this string 
and if a string ends with a consonant, I have to rewrite the last letter and add "ay" to it.

My code is:

```
def change_str():
    with open("file1.txt", "r") as file1, open("file2.txt", "w") as file2:
        lines = file1.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if line[-1] in "aiueoy":
                file2.write(line + " " + "way")
            else:
                file2.write(line + " " + line[-1] + "ay")
```

So it has only 1 correct output line. It's the last one because it has no "/n". In other strings line[-1] == \n and my question is how to ignore it and check the last letter.

Comment: Confusing thing: your text mentions you need to replace the ending of a string. Do you mean a *word*, or a *line*? Your code shows the latter, but it isn't clear from your text.

Comment: @Evert: To be clear, it's more idiomatic because it's less likely to break, and it's faster to boot. Reading all the lines into a list means you need RAM proportionate to the size of the whole file, and can't process a single line until you've read all of them, which for large inputs can take quite a while. Reading line-by-line means RAM requirements are only proportionate to (roughly) the longest line in the file, and processing can begin as soon as the OS returns the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open("file1.txt", 'r') as file1, open("file2.txt", 'w') as file2:
  lines = file1.readlines()
  for line in lines:
      if line.strip()[-1] in 'aeiouy':
          file2.write(line.strip() + " " + "way" + '\n')
      else:
          file2.write(line.strip()[:-1] + "ay" + '\n')
```

How about something like this? Uses strip and then adds the newline char back onto the end.

Comment: Strip removes leading, not just trailing characters, and it removes all whitespace, not just newlines.

Comment: Yeah, use `str.rstrip()`. Stripping excess whitespace at the end of the line generally won't break anything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of readlines, you can use:

```
file1.read().splitlines()
```

That way you don't have to strip any endline characters off of the string.